# TFS 2015 shows plain text password for service endpoint

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am using the NuGet Publisher in TFS 2015. It requires a Service Endpoint to be setup in the Administration console. So I set up a Service Endpoint, and it requires a username and password. I store the username and password thinking, oh, good, Microsoft is trying to be secure.

I run the build and in the build output I get the following:

```
\path\to\NuGet.exe push S:\somedir\some.nupkg -s file://server/NuGet/trunk MYPLAINTEXTPASSWORDHERE
```

Obviously that won't do. Any idea how to stifle this behavior? There seems to be nothing in documentation nor on SO about this particular topic.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess the official way to do this is with a locally hosted NuGet repo is with a [NuGet API Key](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds). Since our NuGet feed is just a directory share, there's actually nothing blocking TFS from writing to it, so it turns out I can just put fake credentials in the Service Endpoint setup (I literally used fake|fake) and it will still copy to the directory.